# Django: best way to design one-to-many count viewing

Tags: sql, django, count, one-to-many

I have 2 models A and B, and one A model may be referenced in several B modals:

```
class A(Model):
    name = CharField(...)

class B(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    a = ForeignKey(A, related_name='all_B')
```

In view of A model I want to show how many B objects there are. 
For now I do this:

```
args={'a_all': A.objects.all()}
...
{% for a in a_all %}
   {{a.name}} : {{ a.all_B.objects.count }} <br>
{% endofr %}
```

But, this will do SQL query for every A object, and it is not cool if I have many models in db tables.

So, I want to fetch all counts in only one query.
select_related in this case can't be used, becouse it works only for one-to-one nad many-to-one relations, but not for one-to-many.

Only thing thant comes to my head is to add counter field to A:

```
class A(Model):
    name = CharField(...)
    b_count = PositiveIntegerField(...)
```

And update it when I change relation. But it brings many work to detect all relations change if there are many views that add/delete/rewrite "a" field of "B" modal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
a_all = A.objects.all().annotate(b_count =Count('b'))
```

This will add a new field b_count with every object of A.
Then in your template you can do something like

```
 {% for a in a_all %}
   {{a.name}} : {{ a.b_count }} <br>
{% endofr %}
```

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
A.objects.all().annotate(b_count = Count('b'))
```

then for each instance of A, you can do a_instance.b_count

Comment: Thanks! It works. One more question, is it possible to Count b objects with some field filter, e.g. "count all b where b.visible == true", if I have visible field in B model ?